# Как найти максимальный элемент каждой строки двумерного массива и присвоить его значение одномерному массиву

Tags: c++, windows

Я создал два динамических массива, двумерный и одномерный (arrA[n][m] и arrB[n])
Помогите найти ошибку в цикле. В некоторых строках находит максимальный элемент, во других же находит мусор.

```
int maxv = A - 1, nextv; // A - минимальный возможный элемент массива при генерации
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        if (maxv < (nextv = arrA[i][j]))
        {
            maxv = nextv;
            arrB[i] = maxv;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: можете скинуть полный код если не трудно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас после того, как в строке найден максимальный элемент, он и остается в `maxv`... Эту переменную надо инициализировать для каждой строки:

```
int maxv = A - 1, nextv; // A - минимальный возможный элемент массива при генерации
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    maxv = A - 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        if (maxv < (nextv = arrA[i][j]))
        {
            maxv = nextv;
            arrB[i] = maxv;
        }
    }
}
```

Но без этой переменной можно и обойтись совсем :)

Answer (score 2):

Вообще то это должен быть комментарий, но пока мне не дозволено (не хватает рейтинга), чтобы их оставлять.

Ваша проблема в том, что Вы не производите сброс maxv перед входом во внутренний цикл, если конечно я правильно понял задачу.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще для таких вещей есть отладчик. Но вот исправленный вариант:

```
int maxv = A - 1, nextv; // На самом деле эти переменные не нужны
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    arrB[i] = arrA[i][0];
    for (int j = 1; j < m; j++)
    {
        if (arrB[i] < arrA[i][j])
        {
            arrB[i] = arrA[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Необходимости использовать дополнительные переменные тут нет.